# Adding specific lines to a file with Ruby

Tags: ruby

Im trying to edit a file with a ruby scriopt to add a html tag eg  at the beginning of the file and line breaks eg. 
 at the end of each line.

Cannot find a clear example to do this.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code that does what you need(you need to call the modify_file function):

```
def add_tag(tag, str)
  return "<#{tag}>\n#{str}\n</#{tag}>"
end

def modify_file(filename)
  content = ""
  File.open(filename){|file| content = file.read}
  content.gsub(/\n/, "</br>\n")
  content = add_tag("html", content)
  File.open(filename, "w") {|file| file.write(content)}
end
```

Comment: Thank! thats great - Im getting the HTML tags at the beginning and end of the file - but not getting the breaks at the end of each line. I would assume the content.gsub line is trying to replace new line characters with breaks. The file I am editing has no new line characters and is actually a log file. Any way to just simply add the breaks at the end of each line in the file?

Comment: Hmm if the line endings in your file are '\r' the above code will not work. You can try to do content.gsub("\n", "</br>\n").gsub("\r","</br>\r")

Comment: There are no line endings in the file. I just need to add html breaks to the end of the existing lines.

Comment: How do you define lines then? A line is something ending with line breaks. If there are no line breaks, then the whole file is a single line.

Comment: hehe - ok fair enough - so the \n would just be defining the end of the line - not the fact that \n has to exist in the actual file.

Comment: Ok - tried again....and...it worked!! Thanks so much! I really appreciate your help - your original code above worked....I was being an ignoramus. Thanks again!!!